# Sumation of tree

Tags: haskell

So for this problem I tried to take the sum of all leaves in a tree. But it's shooting an error every time. I am providing a snippet of the code I wrote.

Sample case

```
t1 =NODE 1 (NODE 2 (NODE 3 (LEAF 4) (LEAF 5)) (LEAF 6)) (NODE 7 (LEAF 8) (LEAF 9))
```

Answer should be 32.

```
data Tree a = LEAF a | NODE a  (Tree a)  (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

tre (LEAF a) = a
tre (NODE a (Tree b) (Tree c)) = [Tree b, Tree c]

sum [] accum = []
sum list@(x:xs) accum = if tre x == Int 
                        then sumTree xs (accum + x) 
                        else sumTree x accum

sumTree :: Num p => Tree p -> p
sumTree p accum= let
                list = tre p
                in sum list accum
```

32

Comment: Hints: start by writing the types of all your functions. E.g. `tre :: Tree a -> [a]`. Then fix the type errors first. `tre (LEAF a) = a` does not return a list. In the other case you should recurse and use `++` to join the two lists (and don't forget the value in the node). In `sum` there is no need to check `tre x == Int`, that does not mean anything. Rather, make `sum` work on a `Tree Int`.

Comment: There are a lot of problems here: you mix type constructors (`Tree`) with data constructors (well you use these in your expression), there are type errors, etc. The main error is already in the `tre` function. So I suggest you take a look at that.

Comment: `But it's shooting an error every time.`. Great - compiler errors are very helpful because they tell you what is wrong with your code, and where! And while some errors can be hard to understand, if you want the Stack Overflow community to help you out you need to share what the error message is, and anything you might have tried or suspected relating to it.

Comment: I would find it a bit (very) odd that a compiler raises an error one time, but not the next time.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The Haskell snipet provided is not the idiomatic Haskell way of solving the problem.

- You don't need the ***tre*** function => use Pattern matching on constructors of your type
- You don't have  to use ***tre x == Int*** let out the magic of type inference

I've provided the following snippet of the code, load it into ghci and use :i Tree and :i sumTree to understand the types

```
module Main where

data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a  (Tree a)  (Tree a) deriving (Show)

sumTree (Leaf a) = a
sumTree (Node a l r) = a + sumTree l + sumTree r

main = do 
  let tree =  Node 5 (Node 21 (Leaf 14) (Leaf 13)) (Leaf 29)
  putStrLn $ show tree
  putStrLn $ show $ sumTree tree
```

Comment: since we just want sum of values at leaves, at node subtracting 'a' is also necessary but thank you. This makes working with trees a lot easier